# Host-context and user state

Tags: polymer

I would like to know if it's possible to combine host-context with element user states.
For example:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <style>
           :host(:hover) {
               background-color: blue; // For all other situations
           }

           :host-context(my-app) {
               // TODO: Apply darkblue ONLY when my-element is hosted within my-app
               // and the user state of my-element is hover.

               background-color: darkblue;
           }
        </style>
        Hello
    </template>
    <script src="my-element.js"></script>    
</polymer-element>
```

I tried a lot of combinations with host-context and :hover but none of them seem to work.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec doesn't specifically mentions this but it is possible to combine both the :host-context and :host selector to get the correct result.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <style>
           :host(:hover) {
               background-color: blue; // For all other situations
           }

           :host-context(my-app):host(:hover) {
               background-color: darkblue;
           }
        </style>
        Hello
    </template>
    <script src="my-element.js"></script>    
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading through [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/), that doesn't appear to be possible.  However, it is possible to do the following.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <style>
           :host(:hover) {
               background-color: blue; // For all other situations
           }

           :host-context(my-app)::shadow #wrapper:hover {
               background-color: darkblue;
           }
        </style>
        <div id="wrapper">Hello</div>
    </template>
    <script src="my-element.js"></script>    
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, was hoping I missed something in the spec that made it possible after all, but using a wrapper as the template root element does the trick.